# perl: save workbook with Win32::OLE not possible

Tags: excel, perl

I've following simplified script (i'm not able to change the Win32:OLE)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Cwd;
use Win32::OLE;   
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

my $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
my $workbook = $excel->Workbooks->Add;
my $worksheet   = $workbook->Worksheets(1);
$worksheet->Range("B1")->{Value} ="Hello";
$worksheet->Range("C2")->{Value} ="World";
# Get current directory using Cwd.pm

my $saveTo = cwd();
$saveTo = $saveTo . '/HelloWorld.xls';
print "$saveTo\n";
$workbook->SaveAs($saveTo);
undef $workbook;
```

And it will produce the following output:

```
D:/workspace/perl/HW_XLS/HelloWorld.xls
```

So i assume the save path is right. But it won't create a file. If i add `$workbook->Close();` its at least asking to close the workbook. but this is all.

While `$workbook->SaveAs("HelloWorld.xls");` is saving my workbook to "MyDocuments\HelloWorld.xls" with the right content.

How to i get this xls written to my cwd() dir, like its written to my documents?

(Enviroment: Windows 7 64bit, Perl: (v5.16.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread)

Comment: Have you tried replacing the slashes with backslashes in $saveTo?  Something like $saveTo =~ s/\//\\/g; before the SaveAs.  Since this is running on Windows, this may be required.

Comment: this solved my problem, can you post it as answer? so i can accept it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is running on Windows, you need to replace the slashes with backslashes in `$saveTo`.  Add a line like

```
$saveTo =~ s/\//\\/g;
```

before the call to `$workbook->SaveAs()`.